# 複数の文字列を格納したArrayListのソート

Tags: java, arraylist

このリストをs1で文字列でソートしたいのですが標準のソートを適用するのは難しい
しかし、一から文字列のソートを書くのはコードが大変そうです
s1とs2は紐づけしたまま扱いたい何かいい案はありませんか？

```
public class MultiList {
    public class String2{
        private String s1;
        private String s2;

        public void setString1(String text1) {
            s1 = text1;
        }
        public void setString2(String text2) {
            s2 = text2;
        }

        public String getString1() {
            return s1;
        }
        public String getString2() {
            return s2;
        }
    }



    public ArrayList<String2> String2List(ArrayList<String> s1, ArrayList<String> s2){
        //二つのリストからオブジェクト型のリストを返す
        ArrayList<String2> String2List = new ArrayList<String2>();
        if(s1.size() == s2.size()){
            for(int i = 0; i<s1.size();i++){
                String2 String2 = new String2();
                String2.setString1(s1.get(i));
                String2.setString2(s2.get(i));
            }
            return String2List;
        }
        return String2List;
    }
}
```

Comment: 標準のソートを使えない理由は何でしょうか？また、コードにバグがあります。String2Listはインスタンスを生成しているだけで中身は何も格納されておりません。s1 > s2の優先順位でソートしたいということでしたらComparatorを自分で定義して使います。http://text4hide.blog14.fc2.com/blog-entry-7.htmlとかが少し参考になるかもしれません。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

標準のソートじゃないなら、[`java.util.Collections.sort(list, comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/7/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator))使ってみて。例:

```
ArrayList<String2> merged = String2List(list_1, list_2);
java.util.Collections.sort(merged, new java.util.Comparator<String2>(){
        public int compare(String2 a, String2 b) {
        return a.getString1().compareTo(b.getString1());
    }
});
```

完全な例:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MultiList {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<String> list_1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        java.util.Collections.addAll(list_1, "c", "b", "a");
        ArrayList<String> list_2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        java.util.Collections.addAll(list_2, "Tom", "Peter", "Harry");

        ArrayList<String2> merged = String2List(list_1, list_2);
        java.util.Collections.sort(merged, new java.util.Comparator<String2>(){
              public int compare(String2 a, String2 b) {
                 return a.getString1().compareTo(b.getString1());
            }
        });

        for(String2 s:merged){
            System.out.println(s.getString1() + ", " + s.getString2());
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<String2> String2List(ArrayList<String> s1, ArrayList<String> s2){
        ArrayList<String2> String2List = new ArrayList<String2>();
        if(s1.size() == s2.size()){
            for(int i = 0; i<s1.size();i++){
                String2 String2 = new String2();
                String2.setString1(s1.get(i));
                String2.setString2(s2.get(i));
                String2List.add(String2); // 注意
            }
        }
        return String2List;
    }

    public static class String2{
        private String s1;
        private String s2;

        public void setString1(String text1) {
            s1 = text1;
        }
        public void setString2(String text2) {
            s2 = text2;
        }

        public String getString1() {
            return s1;
        }
        public String getString2() {
            return s2;
        }
    }
}
```

その出力:

```
a, Harry
b, Peter
c, Tom
```

Comment: この方法で問題の解決を確認しました
ありがとうございました

Comment: @RyuHayabusa,  どういたしまして

Answer (score 4):

テクいことやるより、`Comparable`を実装して標準のソートを使うのが一番早いと思います。

```
// 複数のリストではなく、複数の文字列なのでクラス名変更
public class MultiString implements Comparable<MultiString>{

    final private String s1;
    final private String s2;

    public MultiString(final String s1, final String s2) {
        this.s1 = s1;
        this.s2 = s2;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MultiString o) {       
        int result = this.s1.compareTo(o.s1);
        return result == 0 ? this.s2.compareTo(o.s2) : result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{s1:"+this.s1+", s2:"+this.s2+"}";
    }
}
```

という感じでs1の順序で比較後、s2の順序で比較する`Comparable`を実装して、

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("serial")
        List<MultiString> aList = new ArrayList<MultiString>(){{
            add(new MultiString("a", "a")); add(new MultiString("a", "b")); add(new MultiString("a", "c")); 
            add(new MultiString("b", "a")); add(new MultiString("b", "b")); add(new MultiString("b", "c"));
            add(new MultiString("c", "a")); add(new MultiString("c", "b")); add(new MultiString("c", "c"));
        }};

        Collections.shuffle(aList);
        System.out.println(aList);
        Collections.sort(aList);
        System.out.println(aList);
    }
}
```

#### 出力

> [{s1:b, s2:b}, {s1:b, s2:c}, {s1:c, s2:c}, {s1:a, s2:a}, {s1:c, s2:a}, {s1:a, s2:b}, {s1:b, s2:a}, {s1:a, s2:c}, {s1:c, s2:b}]
>   [{s1:a, s2:a}, {s1:a, s2:b}, {s1:a, s2:c}, {s1:b, s2:a}, {s1:b, s2:b}, {s1:b, s2:c}, {s1:c, s2:a}, {s1:c, s2:b}, {s1:c, s2:c}]

Answer (score 3):

Java8であれば[ラムダ式](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1403/17/news105.html)で下記のように書けます。

```
String2List.sort((lhs, rhs) -> lhs.getString1().compareTo(rhs.getString1()));
```

メソッド`String2List`でリスト`String2List`をソートして返したい場合は下記のようになります。

```
public ArrayList<String2> String2List(ArrayList<String> s1, ArrayList<String> s2){
    //二つのリストからオブジェクト型のリストを返す
    ArrayList<String2> String2List = new ArrayList<String2>();
    if(s1.size() == s2.size()){
        for(int i = 0; i<s1.size();i++){
            String2 String2 = new String2();
            String2.setString1(s1.get(i));
            String2.setString2(s2.get(i));

            String2List.add(String2); // 追加
        }

        // ソート(Java8)
        String2List.sort((lhs, rhs) -> lhs.getString1().compareTo(rhs.getString1()));

        return String2List;
    }
    return String2List;
}
```

Comment: この方法で問題の解決を確認しました
ありがとうございました